# Work Items & Document details cannot be seen when connected to TFS

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tfs

All of a sudden today I notice that I cannot expand the documents and the workitems folder when connected to TFS.

I tried disconnecting & reconnecting to my TFS server . Restarting my Visual Studio & my system and 
       I still see that I cannot see my Documents & Work Item details. I see little red X's

This happens only to me and none of my colleagues have this problem.
   Is there something I can do about this ?

[image]

Comment: Which versions of VS and TFS are you using? 2010?

Comment: VS 2010 & TFS 2013 .

Comment: Try deleting your local TFS cache, it's under c:\Users\<your account name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\ folder. It may fix it (cache will be recreated next time you connect to TFS).